# Difference between orthogonal and orthogonal to each other?

Tags: number-theory, vector-spaces

I am currently examining the proposition that if the quadratic module $(V, Q)$ is nondegenerate and $V$ is the orthogonal direct sum of two subspaces then the subspaces are nondegenerate and they are orthogonal to the other.

My question is, aren't the two subspaces orthonal by definition of orthogonal direct sum? Or does orthogonal to the other mean something else?

Comment: what book are you reading?

Comment: Serre's A Course in Arithmetic